# In the Palestine Partition Plan, why was Jaffa allocated to the Arab state?

Tags: middle-east, international-relations, israel, palestine, united-nations

I'm reading through the document, "The Origins and Evolution of the Palestine Problem, Part II" by the United Nations. Under the provisions of the Palestine Resolution, they note that Palestine was partitioned into eight sections:

> The territory of Palestine was divided into eight parts. Three were allotted to the Jewish state, three to the Arab state. The seventh, Jaffa, was to form an Arab enclave in Jewish territory (Annex I).
>
> The eight part was to be Jerusalem as a *corpus separatum* under a special international regime... (p. 36)

However, **the document makes no mention of why this seventh partition was made.**

The annex refers to a partition diagram of the region of Palestine. I've copied the relevant portion of [the general map](https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/b/bd/UN_Palestine_Partition_Versions_1947.jpg) here:

> [image]

In this diagram, orange regions are designated Arab, blue regions are designated for a Jewish state, and the green line represents the UNSCOP's proposed boundary.

What was the motivation behind this seventh partition?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

> Jaffa, which has an Arab population of about 70,000, is entirely Arab except for two Jewish quarters.
>
> **<sub>- United Nations Special Committee on Palestine. *Report to the General Assembly*. 1947.</sub>**

[Jaffa](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Jaffa) was a predominantly Arab city with a large Arab majority. Carving Jaffa out as an Arab enclave was a *land-efficient* way of strengthening the proportion of Jews in the proposed Jewish state. The committee feared that, when [Bedouin](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bedouin) populations were taken into account, Jews would be rendered a minority within their own state under the original partition plan.